# How can I make my timeline with Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline, flipboard

I've studied Facebook API for several hours, and googled lots of pages. But I can not find the way get posts list just like my timeline on Facebook app.

I would like to make a Web app that show my timeline posts just like Flipboard. I found an API to get my "story" and "my friends list". But I can not even imagine how to retrieve my friend post that shown on my timeline.

Is it impossible to replicate my timeline on my web app? Only Flipboard can do that? Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 4):

To access the current User's News Feed use the "User/Home" request as described in the [API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home).

In order to gain access to the User's News Feed you will be required to gain the "read_stream" permission. For information on how to request the appropriate permission, read the [Login, authorization and permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/#login) section of the Getting Started guide.

The request to **me/home** will return an array of News Feed items, which are comprised of statuses, pictures, likes, etc.  You can see an example of the result by using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Compare the results to your Timeline and they should be nearly identical (currently I believe Ads/Promoted Posts are excluded from the API)"

Comment: please make your answer a bit more extensive

Comment: Seems like this answer isnt avlid anymore :( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/home

Comment: @Ateik, it has been a few years so this is likely outdated. Also, since this time, FB has begun a review & approval process for all applications which use advanced permissions. ```read_stream``` is very rarely granted any more

Answer (score 2):

Play around with the Graph API Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome

I had to change the permissions within the App and specifically give myself 'read_stream' access, but once that was complete I was able to run a '**/me/home**' Graph API GET Request and return a representation of my timeline. Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

You can get the timeline this way:

```
$fb = new Facebook('{config}');
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken('{getAccesstoken}');
    $request = $fb->get('/me?fields=feed.limit(10000){link}');
       //
 $graphObject = $request->getGraphNode();
return $graphObject;
```

Comment: Please post your questions and answers in English in the future, preferably in greater detail.